# web form application making using javascript in the future

Tags: javascript, vb.net, firefox, webforms

In a vb.net 2010 web form application, I have found some JavaScript statements that will not allow the application to execute when I am using the Internet Explorer browser since some of the objects are obsolete/deprecated. However when I run the application using Firefox, I find that the application runs. I have also noted that some of the Javascript objects in the web form application may be deprecated in the future and to use these items with caution.

Thus if I deploy a new version of the current web form application and tell all users to only use Firefox in the next few weeks, I will create a static executable that everyone can use. Then when some of the objects are not allowed in Firefox, the application will still run since I have not changed the executable, correct?

Would I need create a new version of the application with the Javascript changes that are required?

If this is not true, would you let me know why and potentially what I should do to solve the issue?

Comment: I think this will be hard to help since you don't specify what exactly you are using, which objects. Also, what do you mean by executable? Webform are websites... If the browser decided to stop supporting a technology that your website use, then the browser will not run your site properly.

Comment: AjaxControlToolkit?

Comment: You are correct that a webform is a website. What I am referring to is the link; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features This link shows what objects may be deprecated in firefox browser in the future. Thus I need to look at these objects to decide if the web form app uses any of the items in the list and change the applicable code so the webform runs correctly, right?

Comment: The application does use the ajaxcontroltoolkit also. Is this something that can have deprecated code? If so, what should I be looking for?

Comment: Thanks that answers my question!